# Unable to set Label's background with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am trying to use the "background" attribute to make the background of this label light gray, but it is leaving it as white (no errors given). The odd thing is if I set the "foreground" attribute, it changes the foreground correctly. [Image of problem](https://imgur.com/a/2Zw9mt0)

```py
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("PDF to JPG")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(bg="#d1d1d1")

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="#d1d1d1")
frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=50)
frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window, bg="#d1d1d1")
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=50)

img_label = Label(master=frame2, text=f"Selected pdf: None", font=('Helvetica', 32), background="#d1d1d1")
img_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

On online guides, they say to use bg instead of the background attribute, but that gives me an error that bg is invalid. Using background does not give me an error, but it does not work as expected. (See image above)

Comment: You should include a [Complete, Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If I create an example like this, the label background is light brey as expected (using python3.10 on windows 11).

Comment: Avoid using wildcard import.  Try removing `from tkinter.ttk import *`. Or change `Label` to `tk.Label`.

Comment: Your label background is the same color as the parent frame and the window. So you can't see the difference. Try adding `img_label.configure(background='red')` to the end to see the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the line `from tkinter.ttk import *` as the last import statement, so `Label` will be from `ttk` module.  `ttk.Label` does not support `bg` option.

It seems like your platform is MacOS and some widget styles cannot be changed in this platform.

So use `tk.Label` instead of `ttk.Label` if you want to change the background color.

Note that wildcard import is not recommended.